# How do I ignore the first line in the CSV

Tags: php

How do I ignore the first line and also echo out the data in the csv file in a text area and display the number of records on success.

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[1]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (contact_first, contact_last, contact_mobile, contact_email) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[3])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,"","'")); 
    // 

    //redirect 
    header('Location: batch_import.php?success=1'); die; 

}
```

Comment: perhaps a simple counter variable that you increment?

Comment: why not just read one line outside the actual loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consume it before looping.

```
fgets($handle);
```

Comment: that will skip the first line, but it doesn't count the records or echo.

Comment: Sure, but that's the easy part.

Comment: Nothing's going to display / echo on this page, he's doing a header redirect...